# How to load test a method with Mono/Flux Return Type?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

Let's say we have a function that returns Mono/Flux Wrapper Data Type.

```
 Mono<Integer> compute(int a, int b);
```

How do you load test this method while honoring following constraints?

1. Using minimal threads for load test ( If possible just one thread) - We don't care about the `compute` method internals.
2. Rate limiting - Upper bound on number of parallel executions, In other words upper bound the total in-progress Mono's.We want to slow down instead of unresponsive/unhealthy load test.

Comment: What should the parameters be? Can they be random or do they need to follow some kind of pattern? Usually when we talk about a "load test" we're talking about a specific setup, so it'd also be helpful to say what you're trying to "load" here to test (especially considering we're just talking about one thread.)

Comment: Yes, It need to be random. We want to make sure `compute` is not caching and performing better than expected.